# Error building release on Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, ant

I'm trying to build a Phonegap/Cordova for android platform using

```
ant release
```

but i get the following error

```
Buildfile: /Users/delgiudices/Dev/phonegap/wein2/platforms/android/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource anttasks.properties. It could not be found.
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource emma_ant.properties. It could not be found.

-set-mode-check:

-set-release-mode:

BUILD FAILED
/Users/delgiudices/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools/ant/build.xml:1113: Problem: failed to create task or type xpath
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using the cordova CLI?

Comment: Have you tried `cordova build android --release`?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have this line right in your local.properties, that was my error

```
sdk.dir=/Path/To/android-sdk/
```